# Relative Path when linking a pdf to a feature

Tags: qgis, pdf, actions, path

I'm trying to link PDF to features in QGIS. I do that by putting the path in a column named "PDF" and execute the default open action or a generic action command.

So basically I don't have any problems when putting the absolute path, but when I try putting the relative path, it doesn't work. For example, `./PDF/example.pdf` doesn't work but `C:/Users/myname/Desktop/project/PDF/example.pdf` works. If I'm correct, the `.` is supposed to be where the project file is.

So far, these two methods worked for opening a pdf:

The default open action and this as action text:

```
[%"PDF"%]
```

without "enable capture"

or

with a generic action :

```
cmd /c [%"PDF"%]
```

or

```
cmd /c [%"PDF"%]
```

(both worked at one point, I think it was depending if I put `""` in the path column).

I tried several things, for example replacing the `/` with `\` or putting `""` in the path column but nothing works and I can't open pdf file with the relative path. I guess my error is simple, but I browsed the net for hours and couldn't find a solution...

EDIT

Even if I change the properties to relative path, the path is still not recognized...

[image: path not in blue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in several ways, depending on you purpose. Here is one way:

1. Create the attribute with the relative path (it should start with './' . Use it as append (Adjunto in spanish) in formulary. (Porperties)

[image]

2. Go to the formulary of a point and see if it is now in hyperlinked blue.

[image]

---

**Update: 2022-01-26**

You can compose the route with a function like this.

```
[%concat(@project_folder , "PDFDIRWIN" )%]
```

Where PDFDIRWIN is the relative path without the starting point (you can keep ip and rewrite the function removing it if you prefer).

[image]

Don't know why it does't work directly with relatives, but with this you can do the same.

Comment: I just tried it but the path was not in blue, and therefore I still can't open it... (see my edit)

Comment: THANK YOU, after trying everything even Python, this finally worked !!! thanks so much

Comment: I'm glad it worked :-)

Comment: I have a last little thing to ask... So it works when my path is like this : `/PDF/pdf01.pdf`, but if I want the path like this: `PDF/pdf01.pdf`, why doesn't this `[%concat(@project_folder , "/", "DirPDF" )%]` work ?

Comment: In QGIS keep the "" for the attributes and '' for text. So '/' should work.

Comment: Yep I was going to comment that strangely, single quote worked, I had no idea why until now, thanks again :)